# What does FCI owners in a WSFC mean and how does it prevent adding replica to same WSFC?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, sql-server-2019, failover-cluster-instance

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/prereqs-restrictions-recommendations-always-on-availability?view=sql-server-ver16#RestrictionsFCI

> The cluster nodes of an FCI can host only one replica for a given
> availability group: If you add an availability replica on an FCI, the
> WSFC nodes that are possible FCI owners cannot host another replica
> for the same availability group. To avoid possible conflicts, it is
> recommended to configure possible owners for the failover cluster
> instance. This will prevent potentially causing a single WSFC from
> attempting to host two availability replicas for the same availability
> group.

My understanding is that - In a FCI there can be 2 nodes that share the same disk. SQL server service is running only on 1 node. When there is a failover, the SQL server service starts up on the other node.

> The cluster nodes of an FCI can host only one replica for a given
> availability group

This means the FCI cannot host both the primary and secondary replica. I understand this is true because at a time only 1 node of an FCI is active. So only 1 node can hold the replica.

> If you add an availability replica on an FCI, the
> WSFC nodes that are possible FCI owners cannot host another replica
> for the same availability group.

**Question 1:
At a time only 1 WSFC node can own the FCI. So why do they say `WSFC nodes that are possible FCI owners`? Can you explain me the above quote in simple words?**

> To avoid possible conflicts, it is
> recommended to configure possible owners for the failover cluster
> instance. This will prevent potentially causing a single WSFC from
> attempting to host two availability replicas for the same availability
> group.

**Question 2:
Where is the configuration for FCI owner made? And how does this configuration prevent potentially causing a single WSFC from attempting to host two availability replicas for the same availability group?**

Answer (score 3):

Think of Availability Groups and FCIs at different levels.

1. An Availability group is a standalone instance of SQL Server. Each node is a unique instance of SQL Server and is live.
2. FCI is a single logical instance of SQL Server installed within a cluster. Regardless of how many nodes you have, you still only have one logical instance of SQL Server.

With that said, when configuring an Availability Group, SQL Server does not care if the instances joining the Availability Group are standalone SQL Server installations or FCI installations.

In regard to preferred owners. Let's say you have a 4 node cluster, and two FCI configured on the cluster. One FCI on nodes 1 & 2, and a second FCI on nodes 3 & 4. In that case, FCI 1 should be configured with possible owners of nodes 1 & 2 and FCI 2 should be configured with possible owners of nodes 3 & 4.

The reason for this is to avoid a situation where FCI 1 and FCI 2 are configured as two replicas of an Availability Group and also running on the same underlying VM or physical host. In this case, if a the primary node fails, the AG looses both replicas, since they are running on the same host. This would not be a true HA configuration.

Configuration of owners is made within the Windows Failover Cluster Manager. For a given Resource within a Role, you can open the Properties for that Resource, and configure the Possible Owners on the `Advanced Policies` tab of the Resource Properties. Note that this is different from the Preferred Owner, which is configured on the Role, rather than the Resource.